# Science fiction story(-ies?) about aliens who made historical video available

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I was discussing a story I had read with my sister-in-law that she may have also read.  The story may have been a short story and, if so, appeared at the front of the book that I read.  I would have probably read it in the 80s.  Aliens had conquered earth or maybe just made technology available.  Any criminal incident was made viewable by them via video.  This meant that crime became almost non-existent due to being able to review what happened.  If I remember correctly, religious events were excluded from what the aliens made available.

She had a few details that I did not remember or perhaps it was a different story.  The aliens could detect if people were planning something against them, so you had to hide your thoughts as well which the main character did.  I'm not sure if that means he didn't plan anything against them or figured out some other way.  Also, it's possible the reason against religious video was that they were too popular and bogged down there system when people viewed them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a short story, but your description (at least the first paragraph—your sister-in-law may be thinking of a different story) reminds me of the 1953 novel [*Childhood's End*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End) by [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke). (Clarke's novel was expanded from a novelette called ["Guardian Angel"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91784) (from [*Famous Fantastic Mysteries*, April 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57996+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Famous_Fantastic_Mysteries_v11n04_1950-04_unz.org#page/n97/mode/2up)), but that does not match your description very well—no "time viewer".) *Childhood's End* has appeared in [many editions](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2248); does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2248) look familiar?

Earth is conquered by seemingly benevolent alien Overlords, who enforce peace, provide technology, and make Earth a "utopia". Quoting from Spark Notes [Plot Overview](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/childhoodsend/summary.html) and [Chapters 5–6](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/childhoodsend/section3.rhtml):

> It is the late twentieth century. Both the United States and the Soviet Union are about to enter outer space using nuclear-powered spaceships. Just as both countries close in on the achievement of space travel, a number of giant alien spaceships come down over every major city in the world. Five years later, these aliens, known as the Overlords, have taken control of the entire world. [. . . .] Fifty years later, the Earth has greatly changed. It has become a utopia, where everyone has a place to live and enough food to eat. The Overlords have altered the world and raised the standard of living for everyone.

The Overlords give us the [time viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_viewer) for the purpose of debunking religion. Quoting from Spark Notes [Chapters 5–6](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/childhoodsend/section3.rhtml) again:

> Religion has been almost eliminated due to a device given to scientists by the Overlords. It allows a person to look at any instant in time over the last five thousand years, although there are occasionally gaps in the timeline. But this allowed people to see the true lives of people like Christ and Muhammed, and it did much to eliminate religion as an influence.

*Childhood's End* has been made into a [Syfy channel](http://www.syfy.com/childhoodsend) miniseries.

Comment: Yes, both the title and one of the covers looks familiar.  Let me see if I can find a copy.

Comment: I believe this is the one I was thinking of.  The time viewer described in chapter 6 matches what I thought, although I had the reason for the gaps incorrect.  And murder is mentioned related to the device in chapter 10.  Thanks!

Comment: @greysh Apparently the [SyFy channel](http://www.syfy.com/childhoodsend) is airing an adaptation of *Childhood's End*.

Comment: I'm most of the way through the Syfy version. No time viewer yet.  Also, I don't recommend it.

Comment: I find it unlikely that very religious believers would consider the time viewer accurate. They'd be more likely to treat it as blasphemous/a fake device so it wouldn't make much of a difference.